# Having trouble getting .siblings() to work in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, underscore.js, siblings

I have a form on my site that allows people to create a document containing Sections, each of which contains Steps. Basically, the problem is that I can create Sections just fine, but Steps are not being created for some reason.

The HTML for each Section and each Step is created with underscore templates, which you can see in the two scripts below:

```
<script id="tmpl-section" type="text/html">

    <div class="section">
        <div class="form-group row">
            // inputs
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            // more inputs
        </div>

        <a href="#" onclick="addSection($(this), true)">
            Add section after 
        </a>

        <a href="#" onclick="addSection($(this), false)">
            Add section before
        </a>

        <h5>Steps</h5>
        <div class="step-body"></div>

        <hr />
    </div>
</script>

<script id="tmpl-step" type="text/html">
    <div class="step">
        <div class="form-group row">
            // inputs
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            // inputs
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

When someone clicks "Add section (before or after)", the following function is called:

```
function addSection(element, after) {
    var sectionStructure = _.template($('#tmpl-section').html()),
        $sectionBody = $('.section-body');

    if ($('.section').length) {
        if (after) {
            element.closest('.section').after(sectionStructure);
        } else {
            element.closest('.section').before(sectionStructure);
        }
    } else {
        $sectionBody.append(sectionStructure);
    }
    addStep($(this), true); // '$(this)' should refer to whichever "add section" link was clicked
}
```

(`$sectionBody` refers to the part of the page that contains all the sections.) Basically, it's checking to see if there are any other sections on the page yet for when the page is first loaded, and if there aren't any, it adds one. If there are other sections, it adds another before or after whatever section was clicked. Not super relevant, but I wanted to explain the if statements in there.

Every time addSection() is called, it also calls another function called addStep() to initialize each new section with one step.

```
function addStep(element, after) { 
    var stepStructure = _.template($('#tmpl-step').html()),
        $thisStepBody = element.siblings('.step-body');

    $thisStepBody.append(stepStructure);
}
```

Eventually I will add a link in each Step to add another step before/after like each Section has, but I'm not that far yet.

The problem is, `$thisStepBody.append(stepStructure);` is not doing anything. My guess is that `$thisStepBody.siblings('.step-body')`, which is supposed to point to the `('.step-body')` inside whichever section was clicked, is the problem. I've tried this a ton of different ways, and I don't know why it isn't working.

It seems like it should be a simple thing to do, but I'm worried the rest of what I'm trying to do is so overly complicated that it's messing up in a way I can't even think of.

Comment: Why do you think `$(this)` will refer to the link that was clicked? You haven't done anything to bind the function to the element.

Comment: `element` contains the link that was clicked, not `this`.

Comment: `addStep($(this), true);` should be `addStep(element, true);`, since `$(this)` is undefined, the way your called `addSection()`. But you passed the element as first argument. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
addStep($(this), true);
```

should be

```
addStep(element, true);
```

The `addSection()` function isn't bound to the element that's clicked, the element is being passed as a parameter.